# "Split" one request to multiple servers

Tags: http, proxy, httpwebrequest

Is it possible to split a request to multiple endpoint servers ?

So for example:
If server A receives one request it will then forward it to 3 different servers (B,C and D) which will receive that original request with X-Forwarded-For header.

```
              forward
request => A ========> B  
             ========> C
             ========> D
```

The response for that matter can be a simple 200 OK.

I have played around with HAProxy and Apache's mode_proxy so far with no success.

Also read about [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) but I don't think this is the case here.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by splitting the request this way? Are you simply needing redundant logging of the request?

Comment: Hm. How would I do that? Most networking setups, wether they are doing a proxy request or load balancing will retain a one-to-one relationship between the incoming request and the final destination for that specific request. I think you would need some code in between. I think I'd use mod_perl or a custom apache module in C to intercept the request at an early phase and do the multiple routing with sub-requests.

Comment: not really; I need to duplicate the information to 2 different independent target servers.

Comment: Are all of the servers in the same domain?

Comment: No, each server will be on a remote IP.

Comment: How rapidly do the servers need to be kept in sync? I.e., is it OK if serverD gets updated several minutes after serverA or serverB?